# How to calculate the height of cell with tagViews?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Now, I have one UITableviewCell like this:

```
|--------------------|
|  TitleLabelxxxxxx  |
|   SubtitleLabelxxx |
| tagView(Labels )   |
|____________________|
```

Tagview : https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView

TitleLabel and subtitleLabel are not one line.

I receive data from the backend and set the data to tagViews, titleLabel and subtitleLabel.

I used a storyboard to make this TableviewCell.

I used autoLayout to preset the height of the Tagview.

The value of height is `more than or Equal` 34( one line height).

If the tagViews has one line label, the TableviewCell renders perfectly.

If the tagViews has several tags:

When the TableviewCell first shows, the TableviewCell does not render all tags which are rendered in the tagView.

When I scroll this tableView, all TableviewCell will render perfectly after they scroll into the screen.

I used the `tableView.rowHeight =   UITableView.automaticDimension` to set the height of TableviewCell.

This way can't calculate the perfect height value when the cell first renders.

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView/issues/191

I used this way to fix the bug.